# Converting MovieClip to Bitmap with Dispose()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmapdata

I am working on a mobile game using Flash CS6 with AIR. also design and coding on same platform (not using starling etc.).

I am converting movieClips (static, not animated) to bitmap dynamically and its working fine. But i realize with this process bitmapData caching on memory and with big shapes it takes a lot of memory. Then i decide to after added to stage clear to bitmapData by dispose(). But its removes from stage and anywhere its shown.

My code;

```
var target:MovieClip = new Ex_mc2();
target.x=100;
target.y=300;
addChild(target);

var bounds:Rectangle = target.getBounds(this);
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(Math.floor(bounds.width), Math.floor(bounds.height), true, 0);
var bmpMatrix:Matrix = target.transform.matrix;
bmpMatrix.translate(-bounds.x, -bounds.y); // Draw bitmap
bmpData.draw(target, bmpMatrix);

var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpData);
bmp.x=100;
bmp.y=300;
addChild(bmp);

removeChild(target);
//bmpData.dispose(); I want to use this and i dont want my bmp disappear
```

Searching to solution for one week but i cant figure it out.
So my question is;

Can i converting movieClips to bitmap with freeing to memory? Like adding stage a static png file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BitmapData` -- is actually what's being shown on the screen. The format is almost identical to BMP, but the order of bytes is reversed. `Bitmap` is only a display container, serving to output image content to the screen and providing common DisplayObject APIs.

So, if you use `BitmapData.dispose()`, you are actually freeing the memory occupied by image and obviously after that there is nothing to be shown by `Bitmap` container.

Comment: Thanks, so if i understand it right there is no difference adding stage on static PNG or converting movieclip with using bitmapData? And i must to deal with memory usage?

Comment: Correct. In either case you will have a `BitmapData` object representing image data.

Comment: What you did here can be very useful for performance. For instance, if you have some complicated vector graphics (which is bad for performance), you can convert it to a bitmap on the fly and use it as a replacement. The same goes for complicated structures of nested movieclips with filters added.